# FTP Deleting folder Permission Denied

Tags: permissions, ftp

I'm testing my Android FTP Client app and for that i'm using my computer as an ftp server using python's `pyftpdlib` library. My client is implemented using appache library.
I'm encountering problems trying to delete folders on the server, whether they empty or full, created from the client or not.

```
[I 2015-12-31 21:15:23] 10.0.0.3:35358-[geri] MKD C:\users\geri\desktop\test 257
[I 2015-12-31 21:15:23] 10.0.0.3:35358-[geri] DELE C:\users\geri\desktop\test 550 'Permission denied.'
```

There is no problem deleting files. Same problem occures when the folder's containing files.

I've also tried using `SITE CHMOD 777` command but it doesn't help.
Server (my PC) is running on Windows 8, client on Android.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: @LMFAO_A_JOKE yes to all. My user is defined in my python program that uses the pyftpdlib. This is the only action that gives me this error. My user has every permission.

Comment: @LMFAO_A_JOKE this is exactly what I tried to do, the result is shown in the "code". I've also tried deleting a folder that I've uploaded and folder that was already there, all giving me the same error.

Comment: Are you passing it a command to DELETE? Can you pass it a REMOVE command and see if that makes any difference? Not sure if your client is GUI or command line. Maybe RM or RMDIR?

Comment: @LMFAO_A_JOKE man thanks a lot, I was sending a delete command which is used for files, remove command does the job!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the `REMOVE` command for removing directories rather than `DELETE`.